# clang-format is not formatting C header files (.h) according to its config file

Tags: c, header-files, neovim, clang-format

I am running x86_64 GNU/Linux machine and using clang-format in neovim to format my C code. Additionally I am using my own .clang-format config file that is mostly based on style from Mozilla.

**Changes I do to my config file directly translate to the source files (.c) files I format, but for some reason header files (.h) do not follow the formatting style specified in my .clang-format config file.**
It says the clang-format was ran successfully each time I try to format the header file but the formatting itself is nothing as specified in .clang-format file, what am I doing wrong?

Keep in mind everything formats perfectly as specified in .config-format when I format source files.

EDIT:
I am running the clang-format executable with these arguments (path to my .config-format)

> clang-format --style=file:/home/myusername/.config/formatting/.clang-format

Comment: have you tried adding the `-i` option to your `clang-format` command?

Comment: @JohnDoe This does work when ran from terminal commandline and it formats my header files according to my config file, but fails to work inside neovim for some reason, anyways I will accept this as answer. Also why does it work with only with -i flag enabled?

Comment: i posted an answer, that's strange that it;s not working inside neovim, I don't have experience with it so unfortunately I can't say if there is something particular that messes with `clang-format`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `clang-format` from command line to format a file it is necessary to use the `-i` option.

This indicates `clang-format` to do an `inplace edit` and, hence, to overwrite the file with the new format.

Calling `clang-format` without the `-i` will format the file but not save it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is how `style=file` works. From `clang-format --help`:

```
--style=<string>           - Coding style, currently supports:
                               LLVM, GNU, Google, Chromium, Microsoft, Mozilla, WebKit.
                             Use -style=file to load style configuration from
                             .clang-format file located in one of the parent
                             directories of the source file (or current
                             directory for stdin).
                             Use -style="{key: value, ...}" to set specific
                             parameters, e.g.:
                               -style="{BasedOnStyle: llvm, IndentWidth: 8}"
```

I believe `style=file` is actually the default behavior.  It basically searches up parent directories until it finds a file named `.clang-format`. Basically:

```
./.clang-format
../.clang-format
../../.clang-format
```

It will work if you move your `.clang-format` to a parent directory of your current working directory.

Comment: Formatting already works when I format source files but uses default (I think) formatting when trying to format .h files. From clang-format docs: "When using -style=file:<format_file_path>, clang-format for each input file will use the format file located at <format_file_path>. The path may be absolute or relative to the working directory."